# How do I transfer a note with 6+ images from an iPhone to a Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, notes.app, airdrop

I take notes on my phone (text, to-do lists), take photos from within the notes (click (+) and "Take Photo or Video"), and then need to merge those notes into a larger report on my laptop. I am creating the notes with the Notes app on an iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 12.3.1) and trying to transfer these to a MacBook Pro (Mojave 10.14.5). When these notes have six or more images I am unable to transfer.

I have tried the following three options:

### 1. AirDrop, the ideal solution, and why *it* doesn't work

AirDrop worked fine regardless of how many images in a note as of at least December 2018. Now, AirDrop only works if the note has 5 or fewer images. That notes with fewer than 5 images work, shows that connectivity and settings are not issues.

However, trying to AirDrop a note with 6+ images always fails. I attempt to share the note, click the icon for my laptop under AirDrop, and it almost immediately says "Failed" and my laptop receives no notice to accept or decline.

### 2. Create PDF, an okay option, and why *it* doesn't work

Converting the note, complete with images, to a PDF and then transferring the PDF via AirDrop should theoretically work.

However, if the note has 4 or more images, the share icon -> "Create PDF" option brings up a mostly blank screen that says "Unsupported file format data." Click "Done", "Delete PDF", and try the share icon -> "Create PDF" option again and the Notes app crashes and disappears.

### 3. Collaborate on the note, a good option, and why *it* doesn't work

Theoretically, you can add people to the note to work on it collaboratively.

However, if I share the note from my phone iCloud account with my laptop iCloud account (they are different), it sends an email or message with an invitation that must be accepted in order to see the note on the laptop. I have MFA enabled on my iCloud accounts and accepting invitations does not appear compatible with MFA. I click the invitation link and I successfully authenticate through MFA. Apple.com shows a blank screen and the invitation is not accepted (back on my phone I can see the status is "invited" still). Various browsers and restarts and clearing cookies and relogging into iCloud on all devices and many refreshes and it still just gives me a blank page.

(The official Apple Support Community does not work with MFA either it appears.)

**My question:**

How do I transfer a note with 6+ images from my iPhone to my Mac?

Comment: Why do you have two different iCloud accounts for your iPhone and Mac? I would recommend just the one to work around this issue. It is possible to have multiple iCloud accounts on one device, but only one can be primary. That means secondary iCloud accounts will only sync contacts, calendars, reminders, mail. You can still have different IDs for FaceTime/iMessage, App Store, iTunes Store, and more too.

Answer (score 1):

duplicate the note as many times needed.
erase photos in the duplicate notes so that there are 5 or less of them  pic 1 to 5 in the first note, pic 6 to 11 in the second - and so on ...
airdrop them to the computer - assemble the notes in one (or put in a folder) on the computer.